# Java ArrayList using in JSTL(<c:foreach>)

Tags: java, jsp, foreach, jstl

i want foreach items add arrays list

```
<sql:query var="query"  dataSource="${db}">

   select fname, lname from users where fname='ali'

</sql:query>

<c:forEach items="${query.rows}" var="result"> 

 <% 

  ArrayList l= new ArrayList();
  l.add("${result.fname}");
  l.add("${result.lname}");


 for(int i=0; i<l.size(); i++)
   {
   out.println(l.get(i));
   }
 %>

</c:forEach>
```

output result:

```
${result.fname} ${result.lname}  ${result.fname} ${result.lname}  ${result.fname} ${result.lname}
```

what is wrong ?

Comment: jsp is meant for presentation purposes only , so try populating the list in servlet and passing it back to the jsp . it would be easy to find the errors

Comment: You can't use jstl inside scriptlet.. Please go through JSP lifecycle and tag library...

Comment: @maxx777 the generated servlet will recognize  ${result.fname}   as static value..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't use jstl inside scriptlet..**

Save the value of `${result.fname}` using `<c:set>` in page  scope. And use the variable inside the scriptlet.

e.g.

```
<c:forEach items="${query.rows}" var="result">
     <c:set var="lname" value="${result.lname}"  />
     <c:set var="fname" value="${result.fname}" />

     <%
         ArrayList l= new ArrayList();

         l.add((String)pageContext.getAttribute("fname"));
         l.add((String)pageContext.getAttribute("lname"));

         for(int i=0; i<l.size(); i++)
         {
             out.println(l.get(i));
         }
     %>


</c:forEach>
```

For more information, http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL4.html

http://javapapers.com/jsp/jsp-life-cycle-explain/

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/taglib/handler.html

**UPDATE**

EL attributes are stored in the scope - page, request, session, application
The `<c:set>` tag example doesn't specify a scope, so therefore you could get it like this:

```
 <c:set var="fname" value="${result.fname}" />

  <%
       String fname = (String)pageContext.getAttribute("fname"); 
       System.out.println(fname);
  %>
```

alternatively exploit the feature of the `useBean` tag that creates a scriptlet variable:

```
<c:set var="fname" value="${result.fname}" />
<jsp:useBean id="fname" type="java.lang.String"/>
<%
  System.out.println(fname);
 %>
```

Note that the EL variable and the Scriptlet variable are initially pointing at the same String.
But changing the string in scriptlet code will change the value it is pointing at, while leaving the EL variable untouched.

Comment: when adding l.add(fname); cannot find symbol error

Comment: thank you @Shashi. now code work correct (sorry my English very bad)

Answer (score 1):

As you are adding `${result.fname}` using quotes. JVM considers it as string literals. So you are getting result like this.

Answer (score 0):

use foreach loop in jstl for eg check out the eg [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_database_access.htm)!

and avoid java code in jsp page check out this link

[How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)